# Sequence of national/team flags on cricket ground

Tags: cricket, history

[image]

In every cricket match there are flags which are placed around the edge of the cricket stadium as shown in the figure.

I think it is done for all the sports played (though not sure about it).

```
My question is in what sequence they are placed ?
```

Does they are placed according to their rankings ? or there is not any sequence they are randomly placed ?

```
What is the motive behind the flags is there is any special reason / history behind this ?
```

Is it only to indicate about the nations playing the cricket match ?

```
Who holds the decision to place National flags ?
```

Does it depends on the ground authority for that particular match ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is in what sequence they are placed?

- There are no particular sequence. It depends on the cricket board and cricket association related to that ground.

> What is the motive behind the flags is there is any special reason /
>   history behind this ?

- This is just to show respect to that country. It is way of telling that we respect your country and the people there. This is normally done in many other sports as well. I am not sure if it got any particular history for this.

> Who holds the decision to place National flags ?

- This should be the cricket board of that country or the cricket association.